# How to enable log to console Cosmos Client SDK requests

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, logging, azure-cosmosdb

How can I enable log to console of Azure Cosmos Client SDK (NoSQL) of all requests? I would like to see the full query that is being sent to the server.